# HCL Domino 11 - Logo not getting changed from orange to blue after domino upgrade from 8.5 to 11

Tags: lotus-domino, hcl-notes

We have upgraded Domino / Notes from version 8.5.3 to 11.0.1. We have around 8 servers. All servers displays new logo (blue) of Notes except one which still displays old orange one in browser. I have attached the logos of two different servers which are both on Notes 11.0.1. May I know where is this setting or configuration available ?

[image: Logo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most possibly is a browser cache issue (probably cached by a proxy)...

The icon is usually replaced during update. It is located in

...\Domino\Data\domino\html\favicon.ico

If it has not been replaced (showing as orange in Explorer), then most probably more then just the icon is missing: Then better install 11.0.1 again to make sure, all files are replaced properly.

Comment: Thanks Tode. I see that the icon exists in the location that you mentioned but its not updated. Can I just replace this with the one from other server which has the latest one ?

Comment: you can do it... but I think it is not very likely that only this file has not been replaced... who tells you, that the rest of the files is ok? I'd reinstall to be sure...